# dtrace/dtruss command to see what files a command tries to open?

Tags: dtrace

Is there a dtrace one liner that will run a command, and tell me all the files it tries to open?

The Linux strace equivalent of what I'm trying to do is `strace -e trace=file -f cat /etc/passwd > /dev/null`

I am on El Capitan

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try `iosnoop`.  See here: http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/10/10/top-10-dtrace-scripts-for-mac-os-x/

It's been a long time since I used it; the Sierra/High Sierra equivalent is fs_usage, so maybe you have access to that too.  Also if you install Homebrew ([brew.sh](http://brew.sh/)), you can download and install many command-line utilities not already present in the OS.